# Java Palindrome and Reverse Order Integer

Tags: java, reverse, palindrome

Im having trouble in the reverse order section of my code. I'm storing the values in hund, tens, ones, etc. How do I pass the data back to the main method so as to display these numbers in reverse order?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PP53v2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int leftOver = 0;
    int number = 0;
    int num1;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hit #1 to reverse a number. Hit #2 to return if its a palindrome.");
    int selection = input.nextInt();

        switch(selection) {
        //problem 1
        case 1:
        System.out.println("Enter a number to be displayed in reverse order.");
        System.out.println("For accuracy, this must be a five digit number.");
        number = input.nextInt();
        num1 = reverse(number);
        System.out.print(num1);
        break;

        //problem 2
        case 2:
        System.out.println("Enter an integer to see if it's a palindrome.");
        System.out.println("For accuracy, this must be a five digit number. (I.E. 12321 is a palindrome)");
        number = input.nextInt();
        if (isPalindrome(number)) {
            System.out.println("The number is a palindrome." + number);
        } else
            System.out.println("The number isn't a palindrome." + number);

        break;

        }//switch end

    }//main end

    public static int reverse(int number) {

    String leftOver = 0;
    int remaining =0;
    int tenThou = 0, thou = 0, tens = 0, ones = 0; //no need for hundreds

            while (number > 0) {

                tenThou = number / 10000;
                thou = number % 10000 / 1000;
                tens = number % 100 /10;
                ones =  number % 10;

                //remaining = number % 10;
                //number = number / 10;
                //leftOver = leftOver + remaining;
            }//end while
            return leftOver;
    }// reverse method end

    public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {

    int tenThou = 0, thou = 0, tens = 0, ones = 0; //no need for hundreds

    tenThou = number / 10000;
    thou = number % 10000 / 1000;
    tens = number % 100 /10;
    ones =  number % 10;

    if (tenThou == ones && thou == tens)
        return true;
        else
        return false;

    }//method end

}//class end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic

```
while( n != 0 )
      {
          reverse = reverse * 10;
          reverse = reverse + n%10;
          n = n/10;
      }
```

n is the integer(your input).

Comment: Thanks. I've spend an INCREDIBLE amount of time on this project. Being extremely new to programming, I'm still learning slowly but I understand the logic and that's what counts. :)